# How do I accomplish a show on hover effect using html5 and not adobe flash

Tags: javascript, html, hover, show-hide

I have a webpage that needs to show a sliding panel when you hover your cursor close enough to the bottom.

This is before.

[image: mockup]

This is after

[image: mockup]

The closest effect I have seen is in https://read.amazon.com when you read an ebook and the top and bottom controls appear when your cursor move close enough.

If I have placed this question in the wrong stackexchange, I apologize.

**UPDATE:**

Let me explain that even if the screen is scrollable vertically, the bottom sliding up element should always appear at the bottom of the screen so i guess, it is more than just using jQuery.hover.

**Another UPDATE:**

I also want to add that when the cursor hovers close enough but not on the element itself, the element is triggered to slide up.

Comment: The final answer is http://jsfiddle.net/BXGG5/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. To get the hover effect:**

You can consider using JavaScript, more specifically [jQuery .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

HTML:

```
<p>A bunch of text here ...</p>
<div id="toHover">
     <div id="toShowOnHover">This is something to show</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#toHover").hover(
  function() { $("#toShowOnHover").show(); },
  function() { $("#toShowOnHover").hide(); }
);
```

**2. To keep div on the bottom:**

CSS:

```
#toHover {position: fixed; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 40px; }
#toShowOnHover {background-color:red; height: 40px; }
```

Check out the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXGG5/1/) and see if it is what you have in mind

Comment: sorry let me add that the page is scrollable vertically but the toShowOnHover is always bottom of screen. i have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: That can be adjusted by setting CSS `position` options to the `toHover` div, similar to what Sam suggested.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried Sam's jsfiddle. and i need the slide up to appear before i even hovered on top of the div. So i was wondering if there is a way to do that. would this entail using another invisible div above the bottom element?

Comment: yup this is indeed what i had in mind, but of course I want to have it slide up. I believe I can do the sliding effect on my own. Question is, how do I trigger the show effect before i actually hover on the element itself? should i have another element above the bottom element? like this  http://jsfiddle.net/BXGG5/5/ ?

Comment: That could work, just keep in mind that you might be blocking whatever content is behind it, but sounds like you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You poition a div at the expacting place and set a css class and hover effect:

html:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

css:

```
.slider {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.1; (Or 0 if invisible)

}

.slider:hover {

   opacity: 1;

}
```

i create a jsfiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/E7U78/

Comment: sorry let me add that the page is scrollable vertically but the toShowOnHover is always bottom of screen. i have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your jsfiddle. and i need the slide up to appear before i even hovered on top of the div. So i was wondering if there is a way to do that. would this entail using another invisible div above the bottom element?